# How to extract a field from a string with bash

Tags: linux, shell, unix, full-text-search

I have an output from a script which looks like this

```
[{"fileName":"animated.avi","movieId":"34802240145","url":"http://vu.mycdn.me/upload.do?sig=2223a95d7e51832a09d03aa2f23ad3dec0a2c430\u0026expires=1441573849826\u0026clientType=0\u0026id=34802240145\u0026userId=569513266321","accessRights":0}]
```

I need to extract the value of "url".

I tried using sed like this. Suppose the output is in temp.txt

```
sed  '/url/,/accessRights/p' temp.txt
```

Also tried using grep, but was unable to extract it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using cut?

```
cat temp.txt | cut -d ',' -f3 | cut -d '"' -f4
```

The fist cut results in

```
"url":"http://vu.mycdn.me/upload.do?sig=2223a95d7e51832a09d03aa2f23ad3dec0a2c430\u0026expires=1441573849826\u0026clientType=0\u0026id=34802240145\u0026userId=569513266321"
```

The second one extracts the contents between '"' characters.

Result:

```
http://vu.mycdn.me/upload.do?sig=2223a95d7e51832a09d03aa2f23ad3dec0a2c430\u0026expires=1441573849826\u0026clientType=0\u0026id=34802240145\u0026userId=569513266321
```

Comment: I just started with linux, its awesome. Thanks :)

Comment: Yep! Everyone goes through the growing pains. Good luck! StackOverflow will be your home ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a piece of Python code as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
data = [{"fileName":"animated.avi","movieId":"34802240145","url":"http://vu.mycdn.me/upload.do?sig=2223a95d7e51832a09d03aa2f23ad3dec0a2c430\u0026expires=1441573849826\u0026clientType=0\u0026id=34802240145\u0026userId=569513266321","accessRights":0}]
data = data[0]
# if you want to get the next field of 'url', meaning 'accessRights', calling the following one (or the other field)
print data['accessRights']
```

Save it into a file, for instance, named `extract.py`. Then, typing at the terminal:

```
user@linux>extract > temp.txt
```

The result is put in the file `temp.txt`. In this example, `0` is the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm *very* late to the party, so this is more for future reference for other searchers...

It looks like you're trying to process a JSON file. You may find it easier to parse using specialized tools rather than generic tools.  I suggest [jq](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/).

Your particular problem could be solved with:
`cat temp.txt | jq -r .[].url`

The benefit of using specialized tools is that will generally be more legible and robust than generic text processing tools.  Also, even if the format of your source changes slightly (they add another field, for example), the jq code should continue to work, whereas coding it with generic tools may require significant rework.